# How can I directly see that this subgroup has this subfield as its fixed field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm looking at the Galois group for $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$ where $\omega$ is the first primitive third root of unity. I know this is the splitting field for $x^3 - 2$ and, I'm told, that $G = Gal(F/\mathbb{Q}) \cong S_3$ (which, for now, I believe). I can also directly see how most of the subgroups hold their corresponding fixed fields fixed. The only one I can't see directly is how the subgroup of $G$ isomorphic $\\{1, (123), (132)\\}$ holds $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ constant. Since it must be generated by some $\sigma$ I tried

$$\sigma(\omega) = \sigma(\omega \sqrt[3]{2}/\sqrt[3]{2})$$

but I don't have anywhere to go with that. Can someone help me see what $\sigma$ looks like and how I'd get that from the subgroup/group element of $S_3$? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\sigma$ is a *field automorphism*. It respects addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

The automorphism corresponding to $\sigma$ fixes every rational, and sends $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$, sends $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}$, and sends $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\sqrt[3]{2}$. Therefore, it sends $\omega$ to
$$\begin{align*}
\sigma(\omega) &= \sigma\left(\frac{\omega\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)\\
&= \frac{\sigma(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})}{\sigma(\sqrt[3]{2})}\\
&= \frac{\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}}{\omega\sqrt[3]{2}}\\
&=\omega.
\end{align*}$$
So $\sigma$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.